# Selenium not taking screenshot

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Recently I had my Ubuntu Jenkins server running headless selenium tests lovely, and today it won't capture screenshots anymore.

My configuration works on my development laptop, taking screenshots happily. Unfortunately this means debugging and breakpoints is harder as it only fails on Jenkins jobs

The stacktrace is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Build Podunk from master/workspace/podunk/platform/tests/ui/test_create_task_new.py", line 29, in test_task_form
    self.wait_for_page_header(tc.RECORD_CREATE_TASK_PAGE_HEADER)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Build Podunk from master/workspace/podunk/platform/tests/ui/__init__.py", line 176, in wait_for_page_header
    self.take_screenshot('wait_for_page_header')
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Build Podunk from master/workspace/podunk/platform/tests/ui/__init__.py", line 141, in take_screenshot
    self.get_screenshot_as_file(path)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Build Podunk from master/workspace/podunk/platform/tests/ui/__init__.py", line 105, in get_screenshot_as_file
    png64 = self.selenium.get_screenshot_as_base64()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 787, in get_screenshot_as_base64
    return self.execute(Command.SCREENSHOT)['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: Could not convert screenshot to base64 - Error: Invalid base64 data: data:,
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.screenshot (file:///tmp/tmpd1IiNV/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10863)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpd1IiNV/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12534)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpd1IiNV/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12539)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpd1IiNV/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12481)
```

I can't point to a configuration change in my Jenkins setup but would appreciate any help that someone can give

Comment: You should read the guide [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Can you show the code snippet for ../ui/__init__.py and test_create_task_new.py?